# My Program keeps crashing when it gets a SIGUSR1 signal to continue the program from pause()

Tags: c, signals

This is the source code I am working on. I am trying to use signals for string transfer. I don't want to add wait times, so I used the pause() function. When the client sends a signal, it pauses and waits for the server to complete handling it. However, the client doesn't continue when feedback comes and the program crashes. The program crashes with exit code 138. Did I make a mistake about the pause() or this is a different problem?

---

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#define WAIT_TIME 100
#include "libft.h"
#include "ft_printf.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void    send_signal(int pid, char *str)
{
    int i;

    while (*str)
    {
        i = (sizeof(char) * 8) - 1;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            if (*str & (1 << i))
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            else
                kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
            pause();
            //ft_printf("worked");
            i--;
        }
        str++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     i;
    int     pid;

    i = 0;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        ft_printf("Error: Wrong number of arguments.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (argv[1][i])
    {
        if (!ft_isdigit(argv[1][i++]))
        {
            ft_printf("Error: Invalid process ID.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    pid = ft_atoi(argv[1]);
    ft_printf("%s, %d\n", argv[2], getpid());
    send_signal(pid, argv[2]);
    return (0);
}
```

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#define WAIT_TIME 100
#include "libft.h"
#include "ft_printf.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

void    send_signal(int pid, char *str)
{
    int i;

    while (*str)
    {
        i = (sizeof(char) * 8) - 1;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            if (*str & (1 << i))
                kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
            else
                kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
            pause();
            //ft_printf("worked");
            i--;
        }
        str++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     i;
    int     pid;

    i = 0;
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        ft_printf("Error: Wrong number of arguments.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (argv[1][i])
    {
        if (!ft_isdigit(argv[1][i++]))
        {
            ft_printf("Error: Invalid process ID.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    pid = ft_atoi(argv[1]);
    ft_printf("%s, %d\n", argv[2], getpid());
    send_signal(pid, argv[2]);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You need to add a signal handler to catch the signals.

Comment: @dbush So, do I need to handle the signal for the pause to work properly, and does it work for all other signals or only user-created signals?

Comment: "I am trying to use signals for string transfer." am I missing the part where you actually transfer a string?  I realize this is probably for an assignment or something, but signals themselves aren't sufficient to handle data transfer between processes.  And IPC mechanisms to tranfer data (pipes for example) probably won't require signals.

Comment: @erik258 You are right, it's for the assignment. We are using signals as bits. SIGUSR1 means 1 SIGUSR2 means 0. The server takes these signals and processes them to characters. Every 8 signals give us a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pause` function doesn't automatically handle signals for you.  If you receive a signal that you haven't handled while the `pause` function is running, your program will still terminate (or more accurately, the signal will have its default effect).

You need to explicitly add a signal handler for at least the signals you're expecting to receive.  In your particular case the handler doesn't need to do anything.  Then when the signal handler returns, this will allow the `pause` function to return.

Comment: "If you receive a signal that you haven't handled while the pause function is running, your program will still terminate" it would be more accurate to say the signal will have the default effect.  But for USR1 and USR2, that's to terminate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement stopping and starting processes yourself.  SIGSTOP and SIGCONT already pause / unpause a process.

Consider the following code, which forks a child process and stops it, then continues it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
  int pid = fork();
  if( pid < 0 ){
    perror("fork fail");
    return 1;
  } else if( pid == 0 ){
    do {
      printf("Hello world!\n");
      usleep(200000);
    } while (1);
  } else {
    sleep(1);
    kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
    printf("Child stopped\n");
    sleep(1);
    printf("Continuing child\n");
    kill(pid, SIGCONT);
    sleep(1);
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    int stat;
    wait(&stat);
  }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Child stopped
Continuing child
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
```

The child process just prints "Hello world!" every 200ms.

```
    do {
      printf("Hello world!\n");
      usleep(200000);
    } while (1);
```

It is not printed between SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals, indicating that the child process was successfully paused and unpaused.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know that but the project rules don't allow us to use other signals than SIGUSER1 and SIGUSER2.